Compute: $\int_0^\infty \sin(\sqrt{e^x-1}) dx$
Is WolframAlpha wrong or did I do something wrong or made an illegal move?
Here's what I did:
$$\int_0^\infty \sin(\sqrt{e^x-1}) dx=\int_0^{\infty}\frac{2u\sin(u)}{u^2+1}du=\frac{\pi}{e}.$$
I let $u=\sqrt{e^x-1}$. However, WA says that it approximates to $0.6704714$, which is a completely different value.
What went wrong here?

I threw it into WolphramAlpha and it approximated 4, I don't know how accurate its approximation is...

How did you get $\frac{\pi}{e}$?

$\int_0^1 \sin(\sqrt{e^x-1}) dx=0.6704705\cdots$

@Amrut Ayan Wolfram Alpha says its $ \int_{0}^{\infty} \sin(\sqrt (e^x-1))dx = 0.670471$

It’s an extremely oscillatory integrand for large $x$, so I wouldn’t trust a numerical integration to give the right answer.

@NagaSaiPrajith see the bounds

WA gives $$\int_0^{100} \sin(\sqrt{e^x-1}) dx=1.1557273497...$$
$$\int_0^{1000} \sin(\sqrt{e^x-1}) dx=1.155727350...$$ and is not able to give a correct answer for the upped bound $=\infty$

I trust that $\frac{\pi}{e}$ is a correct answer. Your substitution seems to be completely valid.
